# Is there a more effective way to pass a list to an excel file (using Openpyxl)?

Tags: python-3.x, list, openpyxl

at the code below i am passing a list to as many excel columns as the list's length. Could i do it in a more effective way? Ideally i would like to pass the list and to fill a whole row with the results, and then move to the next row to write the next results.

```
#lets say the list has 15 indexes, i just didn't write them 
resultList = []

def save_results():
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Results')
    sheet = wb['Sheet']
    sheet['A1'] = 'TEST1'
    sheet['B1'] = 'TEST2'
    sheet['C1'] = 'TEST3'
    sheet['D1'] = 'TEST4'
    sheet['F1'] = 'TEST5'
    sheet['E1'] = 'TEST6'
    sheet['G1'] = 'TEST7'
    sheet['H1'] = 'TEST8'
    sheet['I1'] = 'TEST9'
    sheet['J1'] = 'TEST10'
    sheet['K1'] = 'TEST11'
    sheet['L1'] = 'TEST12'
    sheet['M1'] = 'TEST13'
    sheet['N1'] = 'TEST14'
    sheet['O1'] = resultList[0] 
    sheet['P1'] = resultList[1] 
    sheet['A2'] = resultList[2] 
    sheet['B2'] = resultList[3] 
    sheet['C2'] = resultList[4] 
    sheet['D2'] = resultList[5] 
    sheet['E2'] = resultList[6] 
    sheet['F2'] = resultList[7] 
    sheet['G2'] = resultList[8] 
    sheet['H2'] = resultList[9] 
    sheet['I2'] = resultList[10] 
    sheet['J2'] = resultList[11] 
    sheet['K2'] = resultList[12] 
    sheet['L2'] = resultList[13] 
    wb.save(datetime_output_results +'.xlsx')
```

Comment: You can `append` lists to worksheets.  This is covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append a list like that(shown in code below), you could also make a `testList` and append it the same way as the `resultList` :

```py
def save_results():
    os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Results')
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet = wb['Sheet']
    sheet['A1'] = 'TEST1'
    sheet['B1'] = 'TEST2'
    sheet['C1'] = 'TEST3'
    sheet['D1'] = 'TEST4'
    sheet['F1'] = 'TEST5'
    sheet['E1'] = 'TEST6'
    sheet['G1'] = 'TEST7'
    sheet['H1'] = 'TEST8'
    sheet['I1'] = 'TEST9'
    sheet['J1'] = 'TEST10'
    sheet['K1'] = 'TEST11'
    sheet['L1'] = 'TEST12'
    sheet['M1'] = 'TEST13'
    sheet['N1'] = 'TEST14'
    ws = wb.active
    ws.append(resultList)
    wb.save('10P_Results.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2):

As your sequence doesn't follow a simple increment rule for alphabets and numbers, you can do something like this:

```
title_sequence = [x + "1" for x in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K',
                 'L', 'M', 'N']]

list_sequence = ['O1', 'P1']
list_sequence.extend(x + "2" for x in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
                                       'J', 'K', 'L'] 
for idx, c in enumerate(title_sequence):
    sheet[c] = "TEST{}".format(idx+1)
for idx, c in enumerate(list_sequence):
    sheet[c] = resultList[idx]
```